# Windows 7 Simulate corrupted profile

Tags: windows, windows-7, roaming-profile, profile

For testing purposes I need to simulate what happens when a user gets a temporary profile.

Desktop Environment: Windows 7 Enterprise
Server: Windows 2012

The user would be setup with a roaming profile and home folder on the server.  I need the user profile to act as if it has been corrupted so that the user is given a temporary profile upon login.  How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing/manually corrupting the NTUSER.DAT file under a test user, or changing the permissions for the user folder so the profile can't be accessed by the user?

Comment: You could try changing the registry key that points to the profile. Point it to a non existing folder. Key is here `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\ CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Comment: Yeah just putting a deny ACE so that the user can't read his or her own profile folder is probably the simplest way to run this test.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user to the guest's group on the target computer. By default that give the user a temporary profile that the system flush after the login.

Comment: Unfortunately my domain restrictions do not allow me to do that.  Any other ways I could do this?  I've tried removing the user's permissions to their profile, but I don't know that this is an accurate simulation.

Comment: @elderberries Rename the profile folder on the server the user want to log into, the local registry key will not be updated, and as such windows will fail the profile loading, and give you a temp profile

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into mandatory profiles.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: You should add more information to your answer.  Why are you recommending this and how does it apply to the question?

Comment: @Patrick Tank you for your wisdom! Then I need advise on what i should do I'll as a question in philosophy section.